# Ionic start page depending on a condition

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing an App where I want to route the user to a input screen when he logs in for the first time and then to the standard login screen when he launches the app for the second time.
Ideas anyone?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a flag, set flag to true for first time then change to false and on false change your page routing. You can use localstorage for flag management.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample posted here.

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/simpleKinveyAngular/blob/master/index.html

The basic premise is to use the `resolve` capabilities on the `ui-router` to determine if the user has logged in to the app or not. Based on the results, you take a different path in the route